# Url folder specified in my project to interact with files

Tags: php, linux, shell, codeigniter, ubuntu

I have a "web site project". In my project I am using the php exec to use the ubuntu package PDFTK to manipulate pdf.

For example I have this line of code(php) in my model, I am using code igniter :

```
 shell_exec('pdftk /var/www/html/IntegrSupCours/uploads/GKAG01_FR.pdf dump_data output /var/www/html/IntegrSupCours/uploads/bookmark.txt');
```

Indeed Im starting from /var/www to access to my pdf file, because I am on ubuntu.

But let's say that I am on a localhost ubuntu pc and I want to migrate my site on a online server what will happend if I am changing to that, because the url string in my shell exec to access at my pdf file will be different ?

Comment: I read your question few times and still try to understand :)).
This path will work on new server if your php will have access there. 
Read more about "open_basedir". You can also create some script for what you need and php using shell_exec can run this script

Answer (score 0):

First of all the remote online server that you are mentioning is a machine with some operating system like ubuntu installed on it.

Also, the path that you are specifying is a path that is generally used by most of the web servers.

It is all about where you are installing your application on the online server. If you install the application at the same location as it is in your local, you will be able to see the pdf file in the online server too.